# Jquery .attr returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

Jquery function .attr returns undefined for the below code snippet.

```
<a class="dropdown-item active" href="#" sort-data="A-Z">
<i class="material-icons">check</i>A-Z</a>
```

What I am trying is this-

```
$('dropdown-item active').attr('sort-data')
```

What I've also tried is this -

```
$('.dropdown-item active').attr('sort-data')
```

Comment: Your selector is incorrect. To match an element with two class names, put `.`s before each class name, `.dropdown-item.active`

Comment: Your selector is wrong. You're looking for `<a class="dropdown-item"><active></active></a>`. When looking for an element with multiple selector, remove spaces and include `.` prefixes on all classes: `$('.dropdown-item.active')`. Also note that `sort-data` is not a valid attribute for an `<a>` element. I'd suggest using `data` attributes if you want to store meta data in HTML

Comment: You should do this: `$('.dropdown-item.active').attr('sort-data'));`

Comment: Thanks everyone...it is working now. I was missing the dot operator. thank you for the quick help.